# How to set maximum time for a key to store in Redis cache

Tags: caching, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

How to set maximum time for a key to store in Redis cache? Is there any configurable parameter for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few examples in documentation through [configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction) or [object expiration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations).

Using configuration:

```
RedisCacheConfiguration config = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
    .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```

Using annotation on a class attribute or method

```
@TimeToLive
private Long expiration;
```

> Expiration times can be set by using the @TimeToLive annotation on either a numeric property or a method